# Wi-Fi related confusion

Tags: wireless-networking

I have some doubt about Wi-Fi.
What I understand from Wi-Fi is that:-
" wireless internet connection "
I am using Sony Ericssion W580i handset having airtel sim.
and have AIRTEL LIVE internet setting.
& surf the net on my mobile no extra settings.
Does this means my mobile is Wi-Fi enabled device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFi refers to a specific set of technologies covered by the [IEEE 802.11 specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) and typically carried on the 2.4Ghz and 5.8Ghz ranges.  It is not any wireless connection to the internet, and in some cases does not provide access to the Internet at all, but rather a local private network.

When you're using your airtel connection, you are not using Wifi.  You are using a cellular data connection (in this case, an [EDGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Data_Rates_for_GSM_Evolution) network).

Comment: EDGE means you are saying my mobile is using 3G network.

Comment: but my mobile is not 3G enabled device.

Comment: EDGE is not 3G.

Comment: but i read an article from internet they are saying:-

Comment: EDGE is a "3G" (third generation) technology. It is considered to work three to four times as efficiently as the prior GSM network standards of "2G" and "2.5G."

Comment: EDGE, which stands for Enhanced Data rates for GSM Evolution, is a faster version of GSM. EDGE is a high-speed 3G technology that was built upon the GSM standard.

Comment: Repeat after me: EDGE is not 3G. **EDGE/EGPRS is implemented as a bolt-on enhancement for 2.5G GSM/GPRS networks**. EDGE just about barely meets the minimum requirements of what's constituted as 3G.

Comment: You mean to say EDGE is just enhancement of GSM/GPRS network not a 3G Technology.

Comment: @Sukhi Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

> **have AIRTEL LIVE internet setting**. &
>   surf the net on my mobile **no extra
>   settings**

Contradictory statements, isn't it ? Airtel Live is just a basic WAP portal. You are billed for data transfer.

And no, your phone doesn't have WiFi

Comment: No extra settings i mean i don't need to configure any data account in my mobile.

Comment: Airtel Live is pre-activated.

Comment: Ok you mean Airtel Live is pre-configured data account.